# toggle css without using toggleclass

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to toggle some css whilst I hover over a div. Normally I would use 'toggleclass' but the new background color doesn't seem to overwrite the existing class so I resorted to the method below.

The issue is how to toggle the css off after the hover.

```
$('#menu_first_home').hover(function(){
$(this).css({ 'border': '10px solid rgba(186, 0, 0, 0.2)' });
$('.search-box').css({ 'background-color': 'rgba(186, 0, 0, 0.5)', 'color': 'rgba(186, 0, 0, 0.5)'    });
});
```

Comment: what is the problem when you use toggle class... can you share the code and the css used in that case

Comment: can u show us a fiddle ?

Comment: when you say toggle class isn't working is it because you have assigned the original colour to the id and then try to overwrite it with the class?

Comment: You should use toggleClass for this. If the rules contained in the new class doesn't apply properly, it's only because you have a CSS specifity problem.

Comment: Sorry bad link - http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=tL9Oqix6Cb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ToggleClass should work, but here is an example for your code to change the css attributes on mouseleave

```
$('#menu_first_home').hover(

function () { // Mouseenter
    $(this).css({
        'border': '10px solid rgba(186, 0, 0, 0.2)'
    });
    $('.search-box').css({
        'background-color': 'rgba(186, 0, 0, 0.5)',
        'color': 'rgba(186, 0, 0, 0.5)'
    });
}, function(){ // Mouseleave
    $(this).css({
        'border': '10px solid rgba(186, 0, 0, 0.2)'
    });
    $('.search-box').css({
        'background-color': 'rgba(186, 0, 0, 0.5)',
        'color': 'rgba(186, 0, 0, 0.5)'
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have CSS classes for border and background color. Add / remove them for hover on and off as shown below -

CSS -

```
.borderClass{border: 10px solid rgba(186, 0, 0, 0.2);}

.backgroundColorClass{background-color: rgba(186, 0, 0, 0.5);
                      color: rgba(186, 0, 0, 0.5);}
```

jQuery -

```
$('#menu_first_home').hover(function(){
   //for hover on
   $(this).addClass("borderClass");
   $('.search-box').addClass("backgroundColorClass");
},function(){
   //for hover off
   $(this).removeClass("borderClass");
   $('.search-box').removeClass("backgroundColorClass");
});
```

Comment: looks like it may be done shorter - `$('#menu_first_home').hover(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('borderClass');
        $('.search-box').toggleClass("backgroundColorClass");
    });`

Comment: but this will toggle class for every `mouseenter` event only and I think OP want to add color when `mouseenter` and remove it when `mouseleave`, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: if u use single function on hover it will be called on `mouseleave` and `mouseetnter`. Looks like result will be same

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery hover method along with css classes to solve it. **hover method** accept two callback function, one when the pointer moves over the item, and one when it leaves:

```
$(item).hover(function() { ... }, function() { ... });
```

Instead of adding styles dynamically, define it in css files :

```
#menu_first_home.hoverClass {
    border-color: rgba(186, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

and on hover, add the class (e.g. "hoverClass") to that particular element, and on mouse out remove it.

Here is the [live working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sb5Lp7m9/).